# Is it not redundant to run tox if you are using GitHub actions' matrix strategy?

Tags: github-actions, tox

With GitHub actions matrix strategy you can specify which versions of python (for example) you want your code to run on, so is there any need to run tox in a GitHub actions workflow?

Is there anything tox offers that the gh-actions matrix strategy does not?

Thanks!

Comment: There is always the advantage with _tox_ of not being tied to a particular CI system. And it works also on your development machine. So you are platform-independent, vendor independent, and so on. For Travis CI, one can simply add the [_tox-travis_ plugin](https://pypi.org/project/tox-travis/) and be quickly done. There are probably similar solutions for other CI platforms, that let you use _tox_ without repeating yourself in the CI configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As you can run `tox` locally. It is generally a good idea to run tests locally before pushing them on eg GitHub.

Also, with `tox` you can create a local development environment as easy as `tox --dev-env dev-env`.

Can't get much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more goodies here (too much for a comment):

Note that you can use [tox-gh-actions](https://github.com/ymyzk/tox-gh-actions) to have GitHub Actions automatically detect which environment to run based on your matrix configuration. This way `tox` will not try to run all environments on GitHub (just the one matching your python), but it will when you test locally. Alternatively, you could manually map tox environments to python versions like so:

```yaml
strategy:
  matrix:
    python-version: ["3.8", "3.9"]
  include:
    - python-version: "3.8"
      tox-env: "py38"
    - python-version: "3.9"
      tox-env: "py39"
```

and then run `tox -e ${{ matrix.tox-env }}` in a testing step (unless you want to use multiple environments for one python version, in which case `tox-gh-actions` might be easier).

You can also cache the `.tox` folders with the `actions/cache@v3` action.